# Calculating the amount of salt to add to water to obtain a specific freezing temperature for the mixture

Tags: thermodynamics, freezing

I am trying to determine a formula which can be used to determine how much salt (specifically sodium chloride) in grams to add to a liter of water in order to cause it to freeze at a specified temperature.

My intention is to add a salt-water mixture to a freezer with a freezing point just several degrees above the temperature of the freezer, so that if the power ever goes out and the temperature starts rising, the [enthalpy of fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_fusion) will be able to absorb a lot of the heat prior to the entire freezer warming up substantially. Plain water would also work for this, but by the time the thawing water is absorbing energy due to the enthalpy of fusion, it's likely that the average temperate in the freezer will already be above 0 degrees C and therefore the food will be beginning to melt.

Considering that saltwater actually freezes/melts over a [range of temperatures](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=1722), ideally the equation will determine the ideal salt concentration for purposes of absorbing heat starting from a given temperature, rather than simply the temperature at which the mixture starts or finishes freezing/thawing.

An additional completely optional bonus follow-up question:

- Would a different commonly available salt (or salt mixture) have a higher enthalpy of fusion at a specific temperature, and therefore be more effective?

Comment: The colligative properties for water apply to low concentrations, so a calculation for high concentrations may be difficult to find.  However, there should be published tables which list freezing temperature as a function of salt concentration.  If necessary, you can obtain a polynomial equation from that data.

Comment: The [phase diagram of salt water](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/D-Bentz/publication/263963700/figure/fig1/AS:613953411481603@1523389308152/Phase-diagram-of-aqueous-NaCl-16.png) could be useful here.

Comment: You may find the theory behind this [freezing point depression calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/chemistry/freezing-point-depression) useful?